# logrotate appending the date to logs in wrong way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, logrotate

I have a rails application and I have setup logrotate for the logs.
The logs are like `production.log`, `sidekiq.log`, `cron.log` in the directory `/home/username/myapp/log/`. I want the rotated logs should be named like `production.log-server-1-2016-08-02-1470119678.gz`. This type of file is also present but one more file is there which is named like `production.log-server-1-2016-08-02-1470119678.gz-server-1-2016-08-03-1470206339-server-1-2016-08-03-1470225672.gz`.

Below are my configuration for logrotate

> /etc/logrotate.d/myapp

```
/home/user/myapp/log/*.log {
    weekly
    size 10M
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    copytruncate
    #create 0640 ubuntu ubuntu
    su ubuntu ubuntu
    sharedscripts
    prerotate

    endscript
    postrotate

    endscript
}
```

> /etc/logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
daily
size 10M
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext
dateformat -server-1-%Y-%m-%d-%s

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    weekly
    size 500K
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    weekly
    size 500K
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

Any help? Basically I want the log file should be named like `production.log-server-1-date-month-year-time.gz` and it should be rotated if the file size increases more than 10mb or weekly.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/logrotate.d/myapp` add dateext and date under myapp configuration

```
/home/user/myapp/log/*.log {
    weekly
    size 10M
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    dateext
    dateformat -server-1-%Y-%m-%d-%s
    delaycompress
    copytruncate
    #create 0640 ubuntu ubuntu
    su ubuntu ubuntu
    sharedscripts
    prerotate

    endscript
    postrotate

    endscript
}
```

Inside `/etc/logrotate.conf` file you can remove the below configuration.

```
# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext
dateformat -server-1-%Y-%m-%d-%s
```